# Golang + MongoDB embedded type (embedding a struct in another struct)

Tags: mongodb, go

Hypothetical, I run an API and when a user makes a GET request on the user resource, I will return relevant fields as a JSON

```
type User struct {
  Id      bson.ObjectId `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
  Name    string        `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
  Secret  string        `json:"-,omitempty" bson:"secret,omitempty"`
}
```

As you can see, the Secret field in User has `json:"-"`. This implies that in most operation that I would not like to return. In this case, a response would be

```
{
  "id":1,
  "Name": "John"
}
```

The field secret will not be returned as `json:"-"` omits the field.

Now, I am openning an admin only route where I would like to return the secret field. However, that would mean duplicating the User struct.

My current solution looks like this:

```
type adminUser struct {      
  Id      bson.ObjectId `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
  Name    string        `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
  Secret  string        `json:"secret,omitempty" bson:"secret,omitempty"`
}
```

Is there a way to embed User into adminUser? Kind of like inheritance:

```
type adminUser struct {      
  User
  Secret  string        `json:"secret,omitempty" bson:"secret,omitempty"`
}
```

The above currently does not work, as only the field secret will be returned in this case.

Note: In the actual code base, there are few dozens fields. As such, the cost of duplicating code is high.

The actual mongo query is below:

```
func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ....omitted code...

  var user adminUser
  err := common.GetDB(r).C("users").Find(
      bson.M{"_id": userId},
  ).One(&user)
  if err != nil {
      return
  }
  common.ServeJSON(w, &user)
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You should take a look at the bson package's inline flag 
(that is documented under [bson.Marshal](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Marshal)). 
It should allow you to do something like this:

```
type adminUser struct {
    User `bson:",inline"`
    Secret string `json:"secret,omitempty" bson:"secret,omitempty"`
}
```

However, now you'll notice that you get duplicate key errors 
when you try to read from the database with this structure, 
since both `adminUser` and `User` contain the key `secret`.

In your case I would remove the `Secret` field from `User` 
and only have the one in `adminUser`. 
Then whenever you need to write to the `secret` field, 
make sure you use an `adminUser`.

Comment: In this case, I am getting a runtime error:
internal server error Duplicated key 'secret' in struct main.adminUser!

Comment: Updated my answer. I didn't realize there were duplicate keys involved.

Comment: Just as a side note for the record, the use of the _",inline"_ tag works even for normal fields (non-embedded/non-anonymous).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to declare an interface.

```
type SecureModel interface {
    SecureMe()
}
```

Make sure your model implements it:

```
type User struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Username string        `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    Secret   string        `json:"secret,omitempty" bson:"secret"`
}

func (u *User) SecureMe() {
    u.Secret = ""
}
```

And only call it depending on which route is called.

```
// I am being sent to a non-admin, secure me.
if _, ok := user.(SecureModel); ok {
    user.(SecureModel).SecureMe()
}
// Marshall to JSON, etc.
...
```

Edit: The reason for using an interface here is for cases where you might send arbitrary models over the wire using a common method.