# Why isn't mongo populating embedded structs?

Tags: go, mgo

I have the following schema for mongodb:

```
package api

import (
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

// Content of a press-release
type Content struct {
    Timestamp   time.Time `json:"timestamp" bson:"timestamp"`
    PubDate     time.Time `json:"pub_date" bson:"pub_date"`
    Title       string    `json:"title" bson:"title"`
    Description string    `json:"description" bson:"description"`
    Sector      string    `json:"sector" bson:"sector"`
}

// ContactInfo for a a press-release
type ContactInfo struct {
    Persons     []*Person `json:"persons" bson:"persons"`  // definition of Persons omitted for conciseness 
    ContactData string    `json:"contact_data" bson:"contact_data"`
}

// PressRelease is a document in MongoDB
type PressRelease struct {
    ID bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    *ContactInfo
    *Content
}
```

I would like to retrieve a `PressRelease`, so in a different package, I have:

```
type mongoClient struct {
    *mgo.Collection
    // other irrelevant stuff...
}

func (mc mongoClient) ListRecentUnhandled(c context.Context) (*api.PressRelease, error) {
    var pr api.PressRelease
    err := mc.Find(nil).Sort("-timestamp").One(&pr)
    return &pr, err
}
```

### Problem Statement

The above `ListRecentUnhandled` only populates `api.PressRelease.ID`.  The values of the nested structures `api.Content` and `api.ContactInfo` remain `nil`.

### Previous Attempts/Work

#### Executable test-case

I first tried to construct an executable test case.  However, I am unable to reproduce this behavior in the Go playground:  https://play.golang.org/p/p0pyuJEwGRJ

**Result:**  failure to reproduce

#### Inspect the contents of the data returned by mgo

I then tried to inspect the data being returned by the `mgo` driver by deserializing it to a `map[struct]interface{}`.  Results were as expected.  The keys I found were:

- timestamp
- pub_date
- persons
- title
- description
- contact_data
- sector
- _id

**Result:** all key-values are present and accounted for, and no superfluous data is contained in the result

#### Verify key and value types using `spew.Dump`.

I wanted to cross-validate results from `map[string]interface{}` to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything, so I installed https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew and `spew.Dump`ed the returned data.  Here are abbridged results:

```
(map[string]interface {}) (len=8) {
 (string) (len=11) "description": (string) (len=4402) "[…]",
 (string) (len=12) "contact_data": (string) (len=107) "[…]",
 (string) (len=6) "sector": (string) (len=8) "sciences",
 (string) (len=3) "_id": (bson.ObjectId) (len=12) ObjectIdHex("5ab52ec79af937109ee5ad3c"),
 (string) (len=9) "timestamp": (time.Time) 2018-03-23 16:43:51.56 +0000 UTC,
 (string) (len=8) "pub_date": (time.Time) 2016-06-06 17:54:51 +0000 UTC,
 (string) (len=7) "persons": ([]interface {}) {},
 (string) (len=5) "title": (string) (len=138) "[…]"
}
```

#### Try to load the nested structs individually

I tried replacing `var pr api.PressRelease`?  with `api.Content` and `api.ContactInfo`.  Both structs are individually populated without issue.

**Result:** The data is valid and can be individually de-serialized into the constituent structs

#### Try to instantiate the embedded structs manually

```
func (mc mongoClient) ListRecentUnhandled(c context.Context) (*api.PressRelease, error) {
    var pr api.PressRelease
    pr.Content = new(api.Content)
    pr.ContactInfo = new(api.ContactInfo)
    err := mc.Find(nil).Sort("-timestamp").One(&pr)
    return &pr, err
}
```

**Result:** same as before (only ID field is populated)

### Questions

What is going on here?

How can I de-serialize a `mgo` query into embedded structs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279952/965900

Comment: @mkopriva brilliant, thank you!  Feel free to add an answer if you like -- I will gladly upvote and accept.